# How to count meta-values in WordPress using MySQL to display to two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, pivot

I am running SQL commands to count a number of Wordpress meta-values but I get in a different form that I desire

```
select 
    sum(um.meta_value = '< 2000') '2000', 
    sum(um.meta_value = '2000-3499') '2000-3499', 
    sum(um.meta_value = '3500-4999') '3500-4999', 
    sum(um.meta_value = '5000-7499') '5000-7499', 
    sum(um.meta_value = '7500-9999') '7500-9999', 
    sum(um.meta_value = '10000 >') '10000>'
        from wp_usermeta um
        join wp_users u on u.id = um.user_id
        where um.meta_key = 'income-range'
```

Output I am getting:

[image: Output I am getting]

I need it to show like this:

[image: Output I want, Ignore Second Column]

```
select 
    um.meta_value,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = '< 2000') THEN 1  END) AS '<2000',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = '2000-3499') THEN 1 END) AS '2000-3499',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = '3500-4999') THEN 1 END) AS '3500-4999',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = '5000-7499') THEN 1 END) AS '5000-7499',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = '7500-9999') THEN 1 END) AS '7500-9999',
        SUM(CASE WHEN (um.meta_value = 'c') THEN 1 END) AS '7500-9999'


        from wp_usermeta um 
        left join wp_users u on u.id = um.user_id
        where um.meta_key = 'income-range'
    GROUP BY um.meta_value
```

I also don't like this output so it has to be two columns:

[image: I don't like this query output either]

Comment: You can improve your chances of getting a response if you include sample data and expected outcome as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want simple aggregation, maybe with a `case` expression to honor the transcoding:

```
select
    case um.meta_value
        when 'c' then '> 10000'
        else um.meta_value
    end as income_range
    count(*) total
from wp_usermeta um
join wp_users u on u.id = um.user_id
where um.meta_key = 'income-range'
group by income_range
```

Comment: This was the perfect query, the previous answer helped

Comment: SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) c FROM wp_usermeta um WHERE meta_key = 'income-range' GROUP BY meta_value

Answer (score 0):

I basically did a COUNT on the specific meta_key and GROUPed BY the meta-value.

```
SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) c FROM wp_usermeta um WHERE meta_key = 'income-range' GROUP BY meta_value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this query does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.